# Password reset over phone number verify issue in flutter app + firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have weird issue. My flutter app using Firebase phone auth to Sign Up user. If user wish reset password he must enter the area code and his phone number. But here comes a problem. When selecting a country code, for example Estonia, which is +372, it automatically displays that you must enter at least 10 numbers in order to press the "Request OTP" button. But in this country the numbers are different, there are 7-10 digits. Is there any way I can remove this control?

[Phone verify image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDNPp.png)

resetpassword_screen.dart

```
class ResetPasswordScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  SignUpController signUpController = Get.find();
  TextEditingController number = TextEditingController();
  String cuntryCode = "";
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  static String verifay = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: transparent,
        height: Get.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: Get.height * 0.35,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: Get.height * 0.03),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Get.back();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 40,
                          width: 40,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(13),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/back.png',
                            color: WhiteColor,
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.3),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: Get.width * 0.25,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Reset Password".tr,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyBold,
                          fontSize: 17,
                          color: WhiteColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: Get.size.height * 0.025,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Already have an account?".tr,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: WhiteColor,
                          fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyMedium,
                          fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Get.to(LoginScreen());
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          " Login Now".tr,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: gradient.circleColor,
                            fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyBold,
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: Get.size.height * 0.04,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/Rectangle326.png",
                      height: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/Background_SignIn.png"), fit: BoxFit.fill),
                //gradient: gradient.btnGradient,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: Get.height * 0.22,
              child: Container(
                height: Get.size.height,
                width: Get.size.width,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    // SizedBox(
                    //   height: Get.height * 0.005,
                    // ),
                    Text(
                      "Please enter your phone number to request a\npassword reset"
                          .tr,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: BlackColor,
                        fontFamily: "Gilroy Medium",
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        child: IntlPhoneField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          cursorColor: BlackColor,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                          ],
                          initialCountryCode: 'ES',
                          controller: number,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            cuntryCode = value.countryCode;
                          },
                          onCountryChanged: (value) {
                            number.text = '';
                          },
                          dropdownIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                            color: greycolor,
                          ),
                          dropdownTextStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: greycolor,
                          ),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: BlackColor,
                          ),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            helperText: null,
                            labelText: "Mobile Number".tr,
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: greycolor,
                              fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyMedium,
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              ),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                          ),
                          validator: (p0) {
                            if (p0!.completeNumber.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Please enter your number'.tr;
                            } else {}
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    GestButton(
                      Width: Get.size.width,
                      height: 50,
                      buttoncolor: gradient.defoultColor,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 30, right: 30),
                      buttontext: "Request OTP".tr,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "Gilroy Bold",
                        color: WhiteColor,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                      onclick: () async {
                        if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                          signUpController.checkMobileInResetPassword(
                              number: number.text, cuntryCode: cuntryCode);
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: WhiteColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> sendOTP(
  String phonNumber,
  String cuntryCode,
) async {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: '${cuntryCode + phonNumber}',
    verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {},
    timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
    codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
      ResetPasswordScreen.verifay = verificationId;
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
  );
}
```

otp_screen.dart

```
class OtpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<OtpScreen> createState() => _OtpScreenState();
}

class _OtpScreenState extends State<OtpScreen> {
  TextEditingController pinPutController = TextEditingController();
  LoginController loginController = Get.find();
  SignUpController signUpController = Get.find();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String code = "";
  String phoneNumber = Get.arguments["number"];

  String countryCode = Get.arguments["cuntryCode"];

  String rout = Get.arguments["route"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: transparent,
        height: Get.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: Get.height * 0.35,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: Get.height * 0.05),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Get.back();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 50,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/back.png',
                            color: WhiteColor,
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.3),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: Get.width * 0.23,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Verification Code".tr,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyBold,
                          fontSize: 17,
                          color: WhiteColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: Get.size.height * 0.02,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "${"We have sent the code verification to".tr}\n${countryCode} ${phoneNumber}",
                    maxLines: 2,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyMedium,
                      color: WhiteColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/Background_SignIn.png"), fit: BoxFit.fill),
                //gradient: gradient.btnGradient,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: Get.height * 0.22,
              child: Container(
                height: Get.size.height,
                width: Get.size.width,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        child: PinCodeTextField(
                          appContext: context,
                          length: 6,
                          obscureText: false,
                          animationType: AnimationType.fade,
                          cursorColor: gradient.defoultColor,
                          cursorHeight: 18,
                          pinTheme: PinTheme(
                            shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            fieldHeight: 45,
                            fieldWidth: 45,
                            inactiveColor: gradient.defoultColor,
                            activeColor: gradient.defoultColor,
                            selectedColor: gradient.defoultColor,
                            activeFillColor: Colors.white,
                            inactiveFillColor: WhiteColor,
                            selectedFillColor: WhiteColor,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                          ),
                          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                          backgroundColor: WhiteColor,
                          enableActiveFill: true,
                          controller: pinPutController,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Please enter your OTP'.tr;
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onCompleted: (v) {
                            print("Completed");
                          },
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            code = value;
                          },
                          beforeTextPaste: (text) {
                            print("Allowing to paste $text");
                            return true;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Didn't receive code?  ".tr,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyMedium,
                              color: greycolor,
                            ),
                          ),
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              sendOTP(phoneNumber, countryCode);
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: 30,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                "Resend New Code".tr,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: gradient.defoultColor,
                                  fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyBold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 60,
                    ),
                    GestButton(
                      Width: Get.size.width,
                      height: 50,
                      buttoncolor: gradient.defoultColor,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 30, right: 30),
                      buttontext: "Verify".tr,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "Gilroy Bold",
                        color: WhiteColor,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                      onclick: () async {
                        try {
                          PhoneAuthCredential credential =
                              PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                            verificationId: ResetPasswordScreen.verifay,
                            smsCode: code,
                          );
                          // Sign the user in (or link) with the credential
                          await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
                          pinPutController.text = "";
                          if (rout == "signUpScreen") {

                            signUpController.setUserApiData(countryCode);
                            Get.offAll(ChooseFevoriteEvent());
                            showToastMessage(signUpController.signUpMsg);
                          }
                          if (rout == "resetScreen") {
                            forgetPasswordBottomSheet();
                          }
                        } catch (e) {
                          showToastMessage("Please enter your valid OTP".tr);
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: WhiteColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future forgetPasswordBottomSheet() {
    return Get.bottomSheet(
      GetBuilder<LoginController>(builder: (context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: 350,
            width: Get.size.width,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Forgot Password".tr,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyBold,
                    color: BlackColor,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 20,
                  ),
                  child: Divider(
                    color: greycolor,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    "Create Your New Password".tr,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyMedium,
                      color: BlackColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: loginController.newPassword,
                    obscureText: loginController.newShowPassword,
                    cursorColor: BlackColor,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyMedium,
                      color: BlackColor,
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter your password'.tr;
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: greycolor),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: greycolor),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: greycolor),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          loginController.newShowOfPassword();
                        },
                        child: !loginController.newShowPassword
                            ? Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/showpassowrd.png",
                                  height: 10,
                                  width: 10,
                                  color: greycolor,
                                ),
                              )
                            : Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/HidePassword.png",
                                  height: 10,
                                  width: 10,
                                  color: greycolor,
                                ),
                              ),
                      ),
                      prefixIcon: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/Unlock.png",
                          height: 10,
                          width: 10,
                          color: greycolor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      labelText: "Password".tr,
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: greycolor,
                        fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyMedium,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: loginController.newConformPassword,
                    obscureText: loginController.conformPassword,
                    cursorColor: BlackColor,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyMedium,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: BlackColor,
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter your password'.tr;
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: greycolor),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: greycolor),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: greycolor),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          loginController.newConformShowOfPassword();
                        },
                        child: !loginController.conformPassword
                            ? Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/showpassowrd.png",
                                  height: 10,
                                  width: 10,
                                  color: greycolor,
                                ),
                              )
                            : Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/HidePassword.png",
                                  height: 10,
                                  width: 10,
                                  color: greycolor,
                                ),
                              ),
                      ),
                      prefixIcon: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/Unlock.png",
                          height: 10,
                          width: 10,
                          color: greycolor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      labelText: "Confirm Password".tr,
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: greycolor,
                        fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyMedium,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                GestButton(
                  Width: Get.size.width,
                  height: 50,
                  buttoncolor: gradient.defoultColor,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 30, right: 30),
                  buttontext: "Continue".tr,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Gilroy Bold",
                    color: WhiteColor,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  onclick: () {
                    if (loginController.newPassword.text ==
                        loginController.newConformPassword.text) {
                      loginController.setForgetPasswordApi(
                          ccode: countryCode, mobile: phoneNumber);
                    } else {
                      showToastMessage("Please Enter Valid Password".tr);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: WhiteColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                topRight: Radius.circular(30),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i already suspect your approach so you may try `validator: (p0) {
  return null;
},` to bypass the check but then there the the question why it is there if not using it, else you have to go with case to case (could use other 3rd party lib to simplify the cases )

Answer (score 0):

The rootcause is the 3rdpackage : intl_phone_field

You use it whit the widget IntlPhoneField. The min max length of the input phone is in the package :

https://github.com/vanshg395/intl_phone_field/blob/master/lib/countries.dart

Unfortunately, there are some mistakes (not only on estonian numbers)

Or you can download the source code of the intl_phone_field and fix it for your needs :

1. In the pubspec.yaml of your project :
   delete the import intl_phone_field to exclude the package.

add those lines to include the flags assets:

```
assets:
- assets/flags/
```

2. In the root folder (same level as lib), create a folder called assets and a nested folder called flags
3. create a folder called intlphonefield in your lib folder
4. go to https://github.com/vanshg395/intl_phone_field and download (Code / Download ZIP) and unzip it in a separate folder outside of your workspace
5. Copy paste assets/flags to assets/flags and lib/ to lib/intlphonefield
6. you have to rewrite your import. Instead of
   `import 'package:intl_phone_field/` you can import your new classes.

At this step, it should work with the same output (min length at 10 for estonian number)

7. Change `minLength: 10,` to `minLength: 7,` in countries.dart just after the estonian conf

```
    code: "EE",
    dialCode: "372",
```

It should be ok.
notes :

- It is a MIT licence.
- It is a workaround, the clean way : open an issue in github and wait fro the nex version

Comment: Where i found pub cache to change that or if i download source code, how can I use this on my code? this is package, I have to make the downloaded package somehow understandable to him in the code.

Comment: I will update my answer today. The source code of this pack age is available on github. You can download the widgets from lib folder here https://github.com/vanshg395/intl_phone_field/tree/master/lib